# Halachick problem with tucking tzitzit into belt

Tags: halacha, clothing, tzitzis, hefsek-interruption

Over Shabbat someone told me they read in Meorot HaDaf Hayomi (מאורות הדף היומי) a while back that there is some problem with tucking the tzitzit into ones belt (he said something about heflesk maybe). He was referring to specifically tucking them in from the top, and then letting them dangle from the bottom. I know that many people such as Rabbi Aharon Lichtenstein where their tzitzit wrapped around the belt form the outside in, though I fail to see how that would be different.

Anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Sounds like Shetuyot to me but you never know.

Comment: anyone know a person who reads the Meorot hadaf pages religiously? maybe they remember...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=zevachim&daf=18b

Zevachim 18b towards the top discusses priestly vestments that are too long, and how if they are held up by the belt, they are considered to be cut. Rabbi David grossman, who gives a shiur on the daf, which can be found on the website above, mentions a brisker chumrah to not tuck tzitzis in to the belt since as per this gemarah the tzizis could be consider to be cut and thus not a beged.

So I think it's a chumrah, a stringency, not necessarily Halacha.

Comment: It seems to me that one would have the same issue anytime his tzitzis are dangling outside, even if the strings are not tucked under his belt, because ultimately the strings are being held up by the belt (or the waistband of his trousers).

Comment: @Dave ...assuming his shirt is tucked in at all. If his shirt is not tucked in then it's not a problem.

Comment: But then the begged would just be considered shorter, as long as the tzitzis are above the belt, they aren't 'separate' from the begged, as opposed to them being tucked in to the belt, which would then separate the tzitzis from the begged. As an aside, I'm not sure the waistband would cut the begged. The gemarah specifically mentions the Avnet, the belt, cutting the begged. There were pants as well and they are not singled out.

Comment: Here we go, Zchus for shlumpy yeshiva boys not tucking in!
What do you think of having the actual begedd protruding a few mm from the belt, would that avoid this problem (and no, not by making it not a 4 corner garment)?